# When can I apply "their" to a singular noun?

Tags: word-usage, pronouns

At what times can I use plural "their" applying it to a singular noun?

For example, I can say:

> Every student has his own learning curve and his own natural
> disposition.

Can I also say

> Every student has **their** own learning curve and **their** own natural
> disposition.

?

And if not, can you, please, explain the reason?

Comment: Yes. "Their" in this case is also known as [singular they](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they). It used to be frowned upon in formal writing and criticized by prescriptive grammar; but in modern-day English, it is commonplace even in the formal styles. (I'm not answering because I'm sure there's a duplicate.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Singular they* is the use of the pronoun *they* or its derivatives as gender-neutral singular pronoun.

> Somebody left their umbrella in the office.
> [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they#:%7E:text=Singular%20they%20is%20the%20use,their%20umbrella%20in%20the%20office.)

As commented, its use has become common, as shown in [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Every+student+has+his%2Cevery+student+has+her%2Cevery+student+has+their&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true)